# Accessing Android Environment directories in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

In my Cordova app I'd like to be able to list the contents of common directories on my Android device; for example:

```
Documents
Downloads
Pictures
```

Down in Android Java-land, these guys are exposed through [the Environment object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html). But since these are platform-specific APIs, they aren't part of the Cordova core, and instead need to be exposed by Cordova plugins.

However, I don't see any equivalent for these in the directories exposed by the [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). Is there another plugin that exposes these? I only really need to pass them in to `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` to list the file contents and read the files.

---

**Update**

User QuickFix provides a solution below -- a plugin that exposes the Android Environment object directories. [I've also created an enhancement report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13480) with the `cordova-plugin-file` plugin to add these directories there. If you'd like to see this functionality added, please vote for it on the Cordova JIRA site.

---

**Update 2**

I also published a small plugin that exposes the directories and external storage helper methods from the `Environment` object to npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-env. I'd still like to see these added to `cordova-plugin-file`, but at least this is available in case someone else needs them.

Comment: I see a reference to Documents in the cordova-plugin-file you link, but you're right the others seem not to be exposed. I think it would be quite easy to make a plugin that returns the environment vars you need.

Comment: @QuickFix - yeah, and the Documents folder appears to be the one inside the app's directory, not the general `/Documents` one that I've seen on some flavors of Android.

Comment: have you tried passing file://storage/0 as the url for window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found no way to get those folders path with built in cordova functions, I made a quick little plugin that allows to get all the paths exposed through the Environment object.

https://github.com/nicolasgrolleau/androidfoldersplugin/

And that shows how easy building a cordova plugin can be.